# Sliding fragment from bottom - up

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I'm trying to create this sliding panel that will show itself once I get a push notification but I cant seem to get it right.

I want the panel itself to be interactive so I want it to be a different fragment.

my main activity xml looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/gradientbg"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#1c1c1c"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    <!--  android:background="#111" -->


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Just for the sake of trying, I set up this simple fragment and trying to listen to it's textView onClickListener:

```
public class Panel extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.panel, container, false);
        view.bringToFront();

        //view.animate().translationYBy(100f).setDuration(1300);

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.animate().translationYBy(-300f).setDuration(1300).start();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fasf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the textView is not responding to any touch events. it's like the fragment is not on to pof the z-index.

Comment: First check if TextView is set to clickable?

Comment: it is, I've added it to the xml. still no go

Comment: also added onTouchListener and it still doesns't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you either reference panel class in the Activity XML or you inflate id/panel so you're actually using the class.

Also, after this issue is fixed, consider making the panel conform in a fashion where drawer_layout can call openDrawer/closeDrawer instead of using the current animation.

Comment: I'm adding this fragment as such:

 ft.replace(R.id.panel, new Panel(), "panel");

Comment: I can see the fragment on screen but it's just not responding to any touch events

Comment: Take a deconstructive approach then.  Remove everything in your view that may interfere with the touch and then test it again.  This will determine if it is the fault of the fragment/window or the other objects in the view.